# How Can I Use the SharePoint People Picker Control in my Custom Web Part?

Tags: web-part, people-picker

I need to add a people picker control to my custom web part. SharePoint has an OOB people picker control (which provides suggestions while typing into the control).

Is there a way to use the OOB SharePoint People Picker control in my custom web part?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem.

below code should be added to ascx file

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 

<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientforms.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientpeoplepicker.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="autofill.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.runtime.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
```

add the below javascript to your code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {

          // Specify the unique ID of the DOM element where the// picker will render.
          initializePeoplePicker('peoplePickerDiv');
      });

      function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {

          var schema = {};
          schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
          schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
          schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
          schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
          schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
          schema['Width'] = '280px';
          schema['Height'] = '55px';

          this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
      }

      function getUserInfo() {

          var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;

          var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
          var userInfo = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
              var user = users[i];
              for (var userProperty in user) {
                  userInfo += userProperty + ':  ' + user[userProperty] + '<br>';
              }
          }
         // $('#resolvedUsers').html(userInfo);

          var keys = peoplePicker.GetAllUserKeys();
         // $('#userKeys').html(keys);
          document.getElementById('<%=RandomList.ClientID%>').value =keys ;
      }




</script>
```

add this div in the place you want the control

```
  <div id="peoplePickerDiv" style="height: 22px" >

  </div>
```

i found the answer at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713593.aspx

Comment: on which version of SP did you implement this? 2010 or 2013?

Comment: @rob.alarcon Going by the assembly version number, it would be SP2013.

Answer (score 4):

add this code in your .ascx page

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="spPeoplePicker" runat="server" Width="350" SelectionSet="User" />
```

You can also refer to link below. it is showing same problem you have now. there is no difference to take PeoplePicker in SP 2010 and SP 2013.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/sharepoint2010programming/thread/7ce91149-e3d7-4178-8c10-4a87e7352197

Comment: This is not the control that DannyRatna was talking about. The SP 2013 control that "provides suggestions while typing into the control" is ClientPeoplePicker as others have answered here.

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint 2013 there is a new control for selecting people and group. This is the ClientPeoplePicker control. Here is a post how to use it : http://spobject.blogspot.com/2013/02/clientpeoplepicker-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Answer (score 2):

Below works for me in SharePoint 2013:

Control in the .ascx:

```
<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker id="spPeoplePicker" runat="server"/>
```

Code in the .ascx.cs:

```
PickerEntity picker = (PickerEntity)spPeoplePicker.ResolvedEntities[0];
SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(picker.Key);
SPFieldUserValue fieldvalue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, user.ID, user.LoginName);
item["User"] = fieldvalue;
item.Update();
```

where "item" is the new SPListItem and "web" is the new SPWeb

Answer (score 1):

just use this in the ascx page. :D works like magic ;)

```
<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker Required="true" ValidationEnabled="true" ID="peoplePicker" 
        runat="server" VisibleSuggestions="3" Rows="1" AllowMultipleEntities="true" CssClass="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" Height="85px" />
```