# How to include built in JS files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I'm attempting to follow the instructions from [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49332/how-can-i-use-the-sharepoint-people-picker-control-in-my-custom-web-part) post.

I've added the Sharepoint links to call the JS files however it seems that they are not included by viewing network activity in my broswer.  I also can't seem to find these files anywhere on the server. I get no errors in my console.

Below is a copy of what my aspx file looks like:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %><%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientforms.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientpeoplepicker.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="autofill.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.runtime.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>

<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"><head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><SharePoint:CTFieldRefs runat=server Prefix="mso:" FieldList="FileLeafRef,Comments,PublishingPreviewImage,PublishingHidden,_PublishingMigratedGuid,PublishingAssociatedContentType,PublishingAssociatedVariations,ReusableContent01,ReusableContent02,ReusableContent03,ReusableContent04,ReusableContent05,ReusableContent06"><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:PublishingContact msdt:dt="string">33670</mso:PublishingContact>
<mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_PublishingContact msdt:dt="string">Dave Maietta</mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_PublishingContact>
<mso:PublishingContactPicture msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingContactPicture>
<mso:PublishingContactName msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingContactName>
<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x01010007FF3E057FA8AB4AA42FCB67B453FFC100E214EEE741181F4E9F7ACC43278EE81100E4632162F09D9946B470959B43B2391B003D704FE3DEA833468B05857CA4326220</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:Comments msdt:dt="string"></mso:Comments>
<mso:PublishingContactEmail msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingContactEmail>
<mso:PublishingPageLayout msdt:dt="string">https://connect.gsk.com/sites/pharma_eu/_catalogs/masterpage/GSK_2013_Brand_PharmaEU_Awards.aspx, /sites/pharma_eu/_catalogs/masterpage/GSK_2013_Brand_PharmaEU_Awards.aspx</mso:PublishingPageLayout>
<mso:PublishingHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:PublishingHidden>
<mso:ReusableContent04 msdt:dt="string"></mso:ReusableContent04>
<mso:ReusableContent02 msdt:dt="string"></mso:ReusableContent02>
<mso:ReusableContent01 msdt:dt="string">&lt;h2 class=&quot;ms-rteElement-H2&quot;&gt;Submit a Nomination&lt;/h2&gt;
​</mso:ReusableContent01>
<mso:ReusableContent06 msdt:dt="string"></mso:ReusableContent06>
<mso:ReusableContent03 msdt:dt="string"></mso:ReusableContent03>
<mso:ReusableContent05 msdt:dt="string"></mso:ReusableContent05>
<mso:RequiresRouting msdt:dt="string">False</mso:RequiresRouting>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml></SharePoint:CTFieldRefs><![endif]-->
<title>Submit a Nomination</title></head>
```

Comment: There is an error in your ASPX on line 3, no opening `<`. I assume it's not like that in your actual solution...

Comment: Also, look in the `Template\LAYOUTS` folder under `15`, usually `C:\Program Files\Common files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the `ScriptLink`s in an `asp:Content` control (most likely you want the "PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" place holder).

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead">
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientforms.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientpeoplepicker.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="autofill.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.runtime.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
</asp:Content>
```

You shouldn't be including your own `<html>` tag either... Your best bet is to follow Robert's suggestion and look at an existing page's markup for a template and make the changes that you need from there.