# Rendering PeoplePicker in JSLink Item Template

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, jslink

I have a custom SHarePoint List that holds a User Lookup.

Now I want to customize the layout in the display or edit form.
In both I must render the PeoplePicker Control.

This is my code

```
(function () {
   var ctx = {};
   ctx.Templates = {};
   overrideContext.Templates.Item= customDisplay;
   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
})();
function customDisplay (ctx){
   var result = ".....<div>MYPEOPLEPICKER_HERE</div>";;
}
```

How can I render the PeoplePicker control? Is that possible to do this in the Item-Template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this.

I must add the JavaScript files for the controls in the Page (with sharepoint designer). After that I could access the Methods to render the control.

The solution based on this answer: [How Can I Use the SharePoint People Picker Control in my Custom Web Part?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49332/how-can-i-use-the-sharepoint-people-picker-control-in-my-custom-web-part)

I also blogged the solution details in this:

http://sharepointsascha.tumblr.com/post/105105848809/how-add-people-picker-into-jslink-viewform

Hope this helps anyone in future.